# Call jQuery function on any change in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a search field. I want to call my jQuery function in every or any change in that search input field. But while I change in that input field and click outside of the field than the jQuery function called.

**html**

```
<input type="search" id="campiagn_search_id" name="campaign_search" placeholder="Campaign Search">
```

**jQuery**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).on('change', '#campiagn_search_id', function() {
        alert("The text has been changed.");
      });
    });
```

While I type `a` and click outside of the field than the alert shown. But I want while type `a` automatically called the jQuery function and show the alert box.

Where is the problem ? Somebody help please ?

Comment: Use `on.('keyUp'...` or `on.('keyPress'...` that `change` should work with `selects`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have attached `change` event to `input`, which gets fired `When the element loses focus after its value was changed` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#campiagn_search_id').on('keyup', function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" id="campiagn_search_id" name="campaign_search" placeholder="Campaign Search">
```

Answer (score 0):

With the search function, I suggest you use `blur` event when user tab or click outside control.

With `keyup` event your API may be called many times.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#campiagn_search_id').blur(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" id="campiagn_search_id" name="campaign_search" placeholder="Campaign Search">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
$("#campiagn_search_id").keyup(function(){alert($(this).val());});
```